# RequestDispatcher causing my textfield value disappear

Tags: jsp, servlets

This code is in my try catch block under SignUpServlet.java.

```
 dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/SignUp.jsp");

            if (uEmail.isEmpty() || uFName.isEmpty() || uLName.isEmpty() || uPass.isEmpty()) {
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "All fields are required!");
            } else {
                // Check duplicate email in database
                PreparedStatement checkEmail = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uEmail = ?");
                checkEmail.setString(1, uEmail);
                ResultSet rs = checkEmail.executeQuery();
            }
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

My plan is to let the website stay at the SignUp page as long as there are error occurred. If there are no error it will bring to log in page.

Problem is when user click sign up button it will bring to the sign up page but the value in the textfield disappear or stays at the previous page.

What I try to achieve is, imagine my sign up form have name, email, and password. Let say user enter name but not enter other two textfields, and they click sign up button. i want the website to stay at the same page without losing the value entered by the user.

How can I accomplish these?

Thank you.